# Как убрать дефолтную метку в яндекс картах при использовании собственной?

Tags: яндекс-карты

`var myMap = new ymaps.Map('my-map', {

```
                center: [52.29778, 104.29639],
                zoom: 4



            });


                var html  = '<div class="projects__item-in">';
    html +=     '<span>Газпром</span>';
    html +=     '<span>Инженерный проект 1</span>';
    html +=        '<span>Иркутск</span>';
    html +=         '<button type="button" class="projects__item-in-link">Подробнее</button>';
    html +=     '</div>';

        $('#my-map').on('click', function(e) {
            var target = e.target 
            if(target.classList.contains('projects__item-in-link')) {
    $('.popup').css('display', 'block');
                $('.projects__item-in').css('display', 'none');
}
        })

var myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([52.29778, 104.29639],
    {balloonContent: html },  
    {iconLayout: 'default#image',
      iconImageHref: 'img/pin-3.png',
      iconImageSize: [64, 88],
      iconImageOffset: [-32, -88],
      balloonLayout: "default#imageWithContent",
      balloonContentSize: [184, 130],

      balloonShadow: false,
     hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
        }
                                     ); `
```

При клике на свою метку у меня вместе с балуном выпадает дефолтная метка. Как её спрятать?
[image: скрин] [image: если без строки balloonLayout: "default#imageWithContent"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете: `balloonLayout: "default#imageWithContent"` уберите эту строчку и метка пропадёт.

Comment: Если убрать эту строку, то метка пропадает, но пропадает и внешний вид моего балуна

Comment: я конечно смог удалить картинку(.ymaps-2-1-68-image-with-content {
    background: none !important;
}), но во-первых это не правильно, во-вторых будет работать только до следующего релиза

Comment: У меня html в балуне остаётся http://jsfiddle.net/u0dh4fcg/ , если у вас нет, то нужен переделайте код на фидле чтобы показать свою проблему. Если же вам нужно полностью переделать балун, а не только внутреннюю часть, то вот подходящий пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan

Comment: Спасибо большое за наводку. Строку balloonLayout: "default#imageWithContent" убирать не обязательно. в ней же сказано #КАРТИНКАсКонтентом, а так как href картинки я не указал подставилось дефолтное изображение. я добавил строку balloonImageSize: [0, 0] и убрал его. теперь всё ОК. Спасибо